# Where are build messages after compile is complete?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

When my react application is building in visual code using

```
npm run build
```

I see warning messages appear regarding the node modules associated with the project, however once compiling has completed they all dissapear and I just see the following message. Even when I scroll up I can't see the messages that appeared during the compile process.

```
Compiled successfully!

You can now view electrum in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000   
  On Your Network:  http://192.168.0.56:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.
```

Is there any way to not have them disappear, or a log somewhere with the warning messages in?

Answer (score 0):

What command are you using?

With:

```
yarn start
```

and

```
yarn build
```

I do not have that problem in VS Code.

What you also can try is to increase VS Code terminal scrollback [image: scrollback setting]

or run building in console outside of VS Code...

or redirect standard error output to standard output with

```
2>&1
```

like this:

```
yarn start 2>&1
```

To get more ideas I guess you have to be more specific ;)

Comment: Apoligies, I update the original question that I run npm run build